# How can I add a image for each button in the table

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

How can I add a image for each button in the table

I have 8 buttons in the table and I want to put different images for each button

I have this how code can be modified to accept 8 images

```
- (UIImage *)cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
NSInteger rowCount = [self tableView:[self tableView] numberOfRowsInSection:0];
NSInteger rowIndex = indexPath.row;
UIImage *background = nil;

if (rowIndex == 0) {
    background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button01.png"];
} else if (rowIndex == rowCount - 1) {
    background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button02.png"];
} else {
    background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button03.png"];
}

return background;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Form an array with all the name of images in it.

```
self.imagesArray = @[@"Button01.png",@"Button02.png",@"Button03.png",...];
```

and then access it inside the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or where you configuring the cell using the indexPath to find the corresponding image from `imagesArray`

```
- (UIImage *)cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
    NSArray *imagesArray = @[@"Button01.png",@"Button02.png",@"Button03.png"];

    return [UIImage imageNamed:imagesArray[indexPath.row];
}
```